# How to get Unreal find headers needed for my code to work?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, windows, file

I am trying to open a dialog to select files under UE4, using [OpenFileDialog](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Developer/DesktopPlatform/IDesktopPlatform/OpenFileDialog/1/index.html).

I added this to my build.cs

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "DesktopPlatform" });
```

In my header:

```
#include "IDesktopPlatform.h"
#include <Developer\DesktopPlatform\Private\Windows\DesktopPlatformWindows.h>
```

Second line suggested by IntelliSense...

I am adding dummy values to my code to start with:

```
void AFileDialogOpenerActor::OpenFileDialog() {         
    FString defaultFile = "";
    FString fileTypes = "";
    TArray<FString> outFileNames;       
    uint32 flags = 1;               
    FDesktopPlatformWindows fpl;
    fpl.OpenFileDialog(0, dialogName,defaultPath, defaultFile, fileTypes,flags, outFileNames);  
}
```

When I try to compile, I get these linker error messages:

[image: linkingerrors]

If I replace the above includes in the header to these:

```
#include "IDesktopPlatform.h"
#include "DesktopPlatformWindows.h"
```

In message log:

```
cannot open include file: "DesktopPlatformWindows.h" no such file or directory
```

If I play around with these includes, I get a mixture of these messages.(Either a linking error, either no such file, or the bunch of linking error messages)
I took a look at containing folders of the headers and they are indeed there and public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/python-scripting/1692181-file-dialog-from-c-in-editorutilitywidget):

I my header I changed the includes to this:

```
#include "DesktopPlatform/Public/IDesktopPlatform.h"
#include "DesktopPlatform/Public/DesktopPlatformModule.h"
```

In the cpp:

```
IDesktopPlatform* fpl = FDesktopPlatformModule::Get();   
fpl->OpenFileDialog(0, dialogName, defaultPath, defaultFile, fileTypes, flags, outFileNames);
```

It looks like, I only needed a path to that header...

Comment: Note that answers to questions aren't the proper place for follow-up questions. For on-topic follow up questions, you should consider posting a new question.